# Wpf add reference from another project error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What am I doing wrong. As you can see, i've added the reference.

I have tried

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion.CustomControls;assembly=SuperProject"
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion.CustomControls;assembly=ion"
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion;assembly=ion"
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion;assembly=SuperProject"
```

[image]

Comment: Have you compiled the `ion` project?

Comment: Its a Library, but its not compiled as a dll. i have imported the library as a project

Comment: What does it compile as if not a dll?  If you've added it as a project reference, then you'll need to compile the `ion` project for the `SuperProject` to be able to find the types within it.

Comment: Also, the following two references are correct (I've created a solution with a dummy referenced `ion` project, and was able to reference dummy types I created in it): `xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion;assembly=ion"
` and `xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion.CustomControls;assembly=ion"
`.

Comment: With the files in a solution works, i know, and you don't need assembly=...
I just want to make all the controls in a separate library and reference them where I need

Comment: Which looks like you've done that, and referenced correctly.  Let's try this: Add the namespace reference `xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion.CustomControls;assembly=ion"` back into your MainWindow.xaml file, and type in `<cc:CustomCanvas />` where you currently have the `<cc` reference in your screenshot, and then compile the entire solution.  What do you get? (I'm assuming ion is a project of type "Class Library", and `ion` is the default namespace of the project).

Comment: The Type CustomCanvas is not accesible.
The class itself has the default contructor(without parameters)

Comment: Is the `CustomCanvas` class declared as `public`?

Comment: Now it is, Thank you so much. And it appears with intellisense when importing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, your reference to `xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:ion.CustomControls;assembly=ion"` is correct, and you just need to make sure that your types that will be referenced cross-assembly are declared as `public`.

Best of luck.